# What exactly is the HTTP_EXPECT header for?

Tags: http-headers

What exactly is the HTTP_EXPECT header for?

I have noticed it popping up in some but not all of my logs, and am curious what it means?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never heard of this header before, but a little research was illuminating.

You can read the [spec for HTTP_EXPECT right here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.20). However, the spec language is perhaps a little dry and technical. The looser explanation is as follows:

Clients can send HTTP requests with large bodies. This would be a big waste of bandwidth if it turns out the server was going to end up rejecting the request for some reason (e.g. no user is logged in or similar). Enter the HTTP_EXPECT header. This header essentially lets the client make special demands of the server; "I the client *expect* that you will pre-approve this message, else… I won't even bother schlepping the big stuff over." On the server side, servers can usually choose to respond in one of two ways:

- bounce back a `100` (please continue!) response, or
- `417` (nope, expectation failed) response.

This has to be done by the server *before* the big expensive request body follows down the stream pipe, so `100` is kind of an intermediate response before your final response (probably `200`), and `417` is a final response that closes the pipe entirely so the client never ends up streaming the data.

Now, in theory the expectation header is extensible so it might be used for other purposes. The client could send an expect for something other than `100`. But the above use case seems to be the primary (if not only) purpose of this header. [See here for more info on the `100` response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html).

Of particular note to JS developers, I think it's worth pointing out that Node has [100-continue support](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/316), but as of today, doesn't yet support [other Expect headers](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4651).